# Which Ubuntu package provides the pypi future package?

Tags: package-management, python, packaging

Which ubuntu package would correspond to the following package at pypi:
`future` (not `futures` or `concurrent.futures`)

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/future
- http://python-future.org/quickstart.html#installation

Answer (score 1):

`__future__` belongs to the Python standard library as provided by the [`libpython2.7-minimal`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libpython2.7-minimal/filelist) package:

```
$ dpkg -S  /usr/lib/python2.7/__future__.py
libpython2.7-minimal:amd64: /usr/lib/python2.7/__future__.py
```

It should already be installed on any version of Ubuntu. In older versions, it would be provided by [`python2.7-minimal`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python2.7-minimal/filelist), but still present anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the package I am using needs the API way:


http://python-future.org/imports.html?highlight=debian#explicit-imports

`from future.builtins.iterators import filter, map, zip`

How do I get this then with a native debian/ubuntu package?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: @user384411 I don't know what that is, but it looks similar to [`future_builtins`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/future_builtins.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

See this one here:
https://github.com/tonysyu/mpltools/blob/7dc4747c1325ad4c24067f44b147fdf1b5376420/mpltools/util.py#L3

https://github.com/tonysyu/mpltools/blob/7dc4747c1325ad4c24067f44b147fdf1b5376420/mpltools/special/hinton.py#L2

https://github.com/tonysyu/mpltools/blob/7dc4747c1325ad4c24067f44b147fdf1b5376420/mpltools/annotation/_slopemarker.py#L2

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think there's a package providing that.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later releases [Python Future](http://python-future.org/) is available as `python-future` in the default Ubuntu repositories:

- [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python-future&searchon=names)
- [launchpad source](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-future)

Install:

```
sudo apt install python-future
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this package is packaged for Ubuntu.

Instead of doing `sudo apt-get install python-future` (which does not work, of course) you can easily do:

```
$ sudo pip install future
```

which will install the package system wide, having the same effect.